# I am working with SQlite database. when my app creshed then the below line show in logcat .. what's its meaning?

Tags: java, android

Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "all": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select * from all

Comment: Please re-edit your question. What have you tried? Have you actually debugged it? Enclose a [MCVE] to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`all` is a keyword for SQLite https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html , you cannot use it as a table name without escaping in your query: http://blog.christosoft.de/2012/10/sqlite-escaping-table-acolumn-names/

If you actually have a table named 'all', then to escape table name, put double quotes around it:

```
select * from "all"
```

In Java that would look like

```
String query = "select * from \"all\"";
... execute that query
```

Comment: thank you so much sir.... Its work.. I got the point ..Again thank you

Comment: You are welcome